# Import "img.svg" into Canvas already used by WebGL

Tags: javascript, webgl

I am drawing a 2D Simulation into a Canvas using WebGL and JavaScript

`let gl = c3d.getContext('webgl', {preserveDrawingBuffer: true});`

I want to add my company-logo "logo.svg" in the corner of my simulation. I wanted to ask what the best possible solution for my porblem is. I am wondering if i need to write another shader and do all the rendering on every simulation step. Or if there is a simple way to import the svg into the Canvas. I need both the simulation and logo to be in the same canvas because i am downloading the end Result as PNG/JPG.

Comment: How are you downloading the end result? `canvas.toDataURL()`? Maybe it's possible to render the output image to a second canvas and then use `2d` context to overlay your company logo, then download final result.

Comment: @teddybeard Hi teddy, this is my download function:

`function download() {
let download = document.getElementById('download');
let image;
image = document.getElementById('c3d').toDataURL('image/png');
download.setAttribute('download', 'image.png');
download.setAttribute('href', image.replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream"));
}
`

Answer (score 0):

This is not a WebGL solution but you could modify your download code to use a second canvas to attach the logo:

```js
var c3d = document.getElementById('c3d');
var c2d = document.getElementById('c2d');

var gl = c3d.getContext('webgl');
var c2 = c2d.getContext('2d');

gl.clearColor(1,0,0,1);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

// Base64 encode WebGL output
var glImage = new Image();
glImage.src = c3d.toDataURL('image/png');


// Base64 encode company logo
var logoImage = new Image();
logoImage.src = "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='50' height='50'%3E%3Crect width='50' height='50' style='fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)' /%3E%3C/svg%3E";

// Combine both images on a canvas
c2.drawImage(glImage, 0, 0);
c2.drawImage(logoImage, 0, 0);

// Here you will download the image as before, but I'm just
// appending it as an img to show that the result is correct
var finalImage = new Image();
finalImage.src = c2d.toDataURL('image/png');

document.body.append(finalImage);
```

```html
<canvas id="c3d"></canvas>
<canvas id="c2d"></canvas>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this downloads a plane white canvas.

Comment: I assume that you created a <canvas id=“c2d”></canvas> element and set it to appropriate width/height?

Comment: I added a code snippet. Does it work in your browser? You should be able to modify it for your use case.